# Run FNDLOAD command on unix server from windows using Jsch

Tags: ssh, unix, java

I'm trying to run an `FNDLOAD` command using Jsch after connecting to my unix server through ssh. But the command is giving me the following error

> bash: FNDLOAD: command not found

Also if I try to read any environment variables like `JAVA_TOP`, `FND_TOP` etc.its not giving any output. But all the other commands like reading a .sh file are working fine using this code. The code is as shown:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ShellExecuter {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "10.111.111.11";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String FND_TOP = "/u01/oracle/fs1/appl/fnd/12.0.0";
        String command = "FNDLOAD user/pass O Y DOWNLOAD " + FND_TOP + "/patch/115/import/abc.lct "
                + "/home/applvis/JAVA/abc.ldt PROGRAM APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME=XX "
                + "CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME=UPLOAD_TOOL";
        try {

            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me in reading environment variables and performing `FNDLOAD` commands. I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

PS: `FNDLOAD utility` is properly installed on the server. I'm able to achieve the desired result when I execute the same command from putty.

**Does anyone have any suggestion or anything to help me with this issue. I'm struck. I have tried many ways but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Here's the solution

FNDLOAD is an OS command line executable. In order to run it we must ensure our enviroment is set up correctly in the shell, before invoking `FNDLOAD`.

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("cd path/to/env/file; . ./envFileName.env;"+ command);
```